# How to draw google chart with data imported from angular service?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-visualization

I am working with google charts and google with the data is being pulled from mongodb via express
I am facing error in using the data extracted by angular service

Here is system.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {SystemValue} from './system-value.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {TruthValue} from './truth_value.model';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SystemValueService {
  selectedSystemValue ! :SystemValue;
  systemValues !: SystemValue[];
  readonly systemURL ="http://localhost:3000/office/system_values";
  readonly truthURL="http://localhost:3000/office/truth_values"
  constructor(public http:HttpClient) {
   }
  getSystemValue()
    {
        return this.http.get(this.systemURL);
    }
    getTruthValue()
    {
      return this.http.get(this.truthURL);
    }
}
```

Here is my component file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {GoogleChartService} from '../service/google-chart.service';
import {SystemValueService} from '../../shared/system-value.service';

import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { viewClassName } from '@angular/compiler';
import { ngxCsv } from 'ngx-csv/ngx-csv';
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-invalid-iata',
  templateUrl: './invalid-iata.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./invalid-iata.component.css']
})
export class InvalidIataComponent implements OnInit {
  private gLib:any;
  private fig1:any;
  private fig2:any;
  constructor(private gChartService:GoogleChartService,private http:HttpClient,public systemvalueService:SystemValueService)
  {
    this.gLib=this.gChartService.getGoogle();
    this.gLib.charts.load('current',{'packages':['corechart','table']});
    // this.gLib.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawToolTipCharts);
    this.gLib.charts.setOnLoadCallback(this.drawChart.bind(this));
  }
   ngOnInit() {
   // this.fig1=await this.systemvalueService.getSystemValue().toPromise();
    //this.fig2=await this.systemvalueService.getTruthValue().toPromise();
    this.systemvalueService.getSystemValue().subscribe(data => {
      this.fig1 = data;})
      this.systemvalueService.getTruthValue().subscribe(data => {
        this.fig2 = data;})
  }
  public mapTable(arrSystem:string[][],arrTruth:string[][])
  { 
  let mapList=[['label','cin','xxx','tcc','status']];
  var i=1;
  while(i<arrSystem.length)
  {
    var keyvalue=arrSystem[i][1];
    var cin="";
    var tcc="";
    var xxx="";
    while( i<arrSystem.length && arrSystem[i][1]==keyvalue)
    {
      if(arrSystem[i][3]=="CIN")
      {
        cin=arrSystem[i][4].substring(0,2);
      }
      else if(arrSystem[i][3]=="XXX")
      {
        xxx=arrSystem[i][4].substring(0,2);
      }
      else if (arrSystem[i][3]=="TCC")
      {
        tcc=arrSystem[i][4];
      }
      i++;
    }
    mapList.push([keyvalue,cin,xxx,tcc,""]);
  i++;
  }
  var k=1;
  while(k<mapList.length)
  {
    cin=mapList[k][1];
    tcc=mapList[k][3];
    xxx=mapList[k][2];
    var y=1;
    var flag=false;
    while(y<arrTruth.length)
    {
      if(cin==arrTruth[y][0] && tcc==arrTruth[y][2] && xxx==arrTruth[y][1])
      {
        flag=true;
      }
      y++;
    }
    if(flag)
    {
      mapList[k][4]="valid";
    }
    else if(flag==false &&cin!="")
    {
      mapList[k][4]="invalid";
    }
    k++;
  }
  return mapList;
  }
  public pieTable(mapList:string[][])
  {
    
    var count1=0;
    var count2=0;
    for(var i=0;i<mapList.length;i++)
    {
      if(mapList[i][4]=="valid")
      {
        count1++;
      }
      else if(mapList[i][4]=="invalid")
      {
        count2++;
      }
    }
   return [count1,count2];
  }
private system_value()
{
  let data_system=this.fig1;
  console.log(this.fig1);
  var arrSystem=[['object_id','label','amid','office_code','office_value']];
    var j=0;
     while(data_system[j]!=null)
   {
    arrSystem.push([data_system[j].object_id,data_system[j].label,data_system[j].amid,data_system[j].office_code,data_system[j].office_value]);
    j++;
   }
   return arrSystem;
}
private truth_value()
{
  let data_truth=this.fig2;
  var arrTruth=[['iata_code','iata_country','city_code']];
   var i=0;
   while(data_truth[i]!=null)
   {
    arrTruth.push([data_truth[i].iata_code,data_truth[i].iata_country,data_truth[i].city_code]);
    i++;
   }
   return arrTruth;
}
private ValidList(mapList:string[][])
{
  let validMapList=[['label','cin','xxx','tcc','status']];
  for(var i=1;i<mapList.length;i++)
  {
    if(mapList[i][4]=="valid")
    {
      validMapList.push(mapList[i]);
    }
  }
  return validMapList;
}
private InvalidList(mapList:string[][])
{
  let invalidMapList=[['label','cin','xxx','tcc','status']];
  for (var i=1;i<mapList.length;i++)
  {
    if(mapList[i][4]=="invalid")
    {
      invalidMapList.push(mapList[i]);
    }
  }
  return invalidMapList;
}
private drawChart()
{
  
 var arrSystem=this.system_value();
 var arrTruth=this.truth_value();
 var mapList=this.mapTable(arrSystem,arrTruth);
 var pieList=this.pieTable(mapList);
 var validMapList=this.ValidList(mapList);
 var invalidMapList=this.InvalidList(mapList);
var primaryList=[["valid",pieList[0]],["invalid",pieList[1]]];
var options={
    title:"Underlying results are",
    legend:"none"
  }
//var data_valid=new this.gLib.visualization.arrayToDataTable(validMapList);
//var data_invalid=new this.gLib.visualization.arrayToDataTable(invalidMapList);
  primaryList[0][2]='<button onClick={}>Valid Data Page</button>'
  primaryList[1][2]='<button onClick={}>Invalid Data Page</button>'
  this.drawPrimaryChart(primaryList);
}
 private drawPrimaryChart(primaryList:(string|number)[][])
 {
  let chart=new this.gLib.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visible_div'));
  let data=new this.gLib.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string','Status');
  data.addColumn('number','Count');
  data.addColumn({
    type:'string',
    label:'Tooltip Chart',
    role:'tooltip',
    'p':{'html':true}
  });
  data.addRows(primaryList);
 var options = {
     title: 'Invalid IATA Values',
     theme:'material',
     width:600,
     height:300,
     legend:'none',
     tooltip:{isHtml:true,trigger:'selection'}
 }; 
 chart.draw(data, options);
 } 
 results_valid(){
  var arrSystem=this.system_value();
 var arrTruth=this.truth_value();
 var mapList=this.mapTable(arrSystem,arrTruth);
 var pieList=this.pieTable(mapList);
 var validMapList=this.ValidList(mapList);
  new ngxCsv(validMapList, 'Valid IATA');
  }
   results_invalid(){
    var arrSystem=this.system_value();
   var arrTruth=this.truth_value();
   var mapList=this.mapTable(arrSystem,arrTruth);
   var pieList=this.pieTable(mapList);
   var invalidMapList=this.InvalidList(mapList);
    new ngxCsv(invalidMapList, 'Invalid IATA');
    }
  }
```

The error I am getting is -->

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at InvalidIataComponent.system_value (invalid-iata.component.ts:113)
    at InvalidIataComponent.drawChart (invalid-iata.component.ts:159)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:372)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:28510)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:371)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:134)
    at zone-evergreen.js:1276
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:406)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28497)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:405)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:1213)
    at zone-evergreen.js:1283
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:406)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28497)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:405)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:178)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:582)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:491)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1600)
    at globalZoneAwareCaptureCallback (zone-evergreen.js:1658)
```

To point out the specific line here is where error was pointing to
var arrSystem=this.system_value(); -->
while(data_system[j]!=null)

please if someone can let me know what's wrong ?
Also the code seldom shows the results but other times it doesn't
also if i do

```
this.systemvalueService.getSystemValue().subscribe(data => {
      this.fig1 = data;console.log(data)})
```

then i do get the the results in console.

Comment: Are you sure the imported data is correct and, is there data to draw? - please, [edit] your question with sample data. I think the problem is in the data - check your code and the imported data. In which line(s) did you get that exception/error?

Comment: The data is absolutely correct as i could draw individual tables of them, also I found the solution its primarily a sort of race condition exists in constructor and  ngOnit so what I did was  async ngOnInit() {
   this.fig1=await this.systemvalueService.getSystemValue().toPromise();
    this.fig2=await this.systemvalueService.getTruthValue().toPromise();
       this.gLib.charts.setOnLoadCallback(this.drawChart.bind(this));
   }

Comment: So, did you already solved your issue? if so, please post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66884020/how-to-draw-google-chart-with-data-imported-from-angular-service#comment118395513_66884020):

The data is absolutely correct as I could draw individual tables of them, also I found the solution.

It's primarily a sort of race condition that exists in constructor and `ngOnit`, so what I did was:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    this.fig1 = await this.systemvalueService.getSystemValue().toPromise();
    this.fig2 = await this.systemvalueService.getTruthValue().toPromise();
    this.gLib.charts.setOnLoadCallback(this.drawChart.bind(this));
}
```